# Best practice for passing JSON containing HTML text?

Tags: javascript, html, json, firefox, express

I am currently working on a service that download an HTML page then send it inside a JSON object. the problem is that chrome accepts the JSON but Firefox detect it as a malformed Object .I would like to know what are the best practice to do this operation ?

Comment: [here is a good guide](http://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/) It states that when including html in JSON you should: **1.** Escape quotation marks used around HTML attributes, **2.** Escape the forward slash in HTML end tags. **3.** Include a space between the tag name and the slash on self closing tags. **4.** Encode any quotation marks that might be included in the HTML content

Comment: thank you steven iseki, your proposition saved my life ;)